# how to build and deploy sakai cle 2.9.x in eclipse

Tags: maven, deployment, build, sakai

> I have imported "sakai" project into eclipse.
>
> How do I build and deploy automatically in "Sakai 2.9.x" in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Building from within eclipse is not recommended. We would suggest that you build from the maven command line. However, I think this is answered here: [How to build and run Maven projects after importing into Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896152/how-to-build-and-run-maven-projects-after-importing-into-eclipse-ide)