# spring data serialization with relational tables

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, serialization

**Problem:** After a long research how I can serialize data from a database with two tables [I have found that tutorial](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Serialization-list.jsp). But I need to get the data out of the database and I do not know how to get connect the data to the database. 
I have found only non-relational samples with one table.

**Question:** Does someone have a sample for the DAO class to get the data for the characteristics out of the database?

**JSON structure** needed:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"CNC",
      "beschreibung":"Metallverarbeitung",
      "characteristics":[
         "id_characteristic":1,
         "id_maschine":2,
         "name":"size",
         "description":"length of maschine",
         "type":1
      ]
   }
]
```

current **JSON structure**:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"CNC",
      "beschreibung":"Metallverarbeitung",
      "characteristics":[

      ]
},

...

]
```

**DAO method** (until now, does not fill the characteristics Array):

```
@Override
    public List<Maschine> list() {
        String selectMaschines = "SELECT * FROM maschine";


        List<Maschine> listMaschine = jdbcTemplate.query(selectMaschines, new RowMapper<Maschine>() {

            @Override
            public Maschine mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Maschine aMaschine = new Maschine();

                aMaschine.setId(rs.getInt("Maschine_id"));
                aMaschine.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                aMaschine.setBeschreibung(rs.getString("beschreibung"));


                return aMaschine;
            }

        });

        return listMaschine;
    }
```

Table structure:

**Maschine table:**

```
maschine_id || name || description
```

**Characteristic table:**

```
id_characteristic || id_maschine || name || description || type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work with spring data you have to add spring data dependency to your pom.xml

then add the annotation for your entities  :

```
@Entity
public class Maschine implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int maschine_id  ;
  private String name ;
  private String description ;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="maschine")
  private Collection<Characteristic> characteristics;
public Maschine() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public int getMaschine_id() {
    return maschine_id;
}
public void setMaschine_id(int maschine_id) {
    this.maschine_id = maschine_id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

// Characteristic entity

```
 @Entity
    public class Characteristic implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id_characteristic ;
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private String type ;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id_machine")
        private Maschine maschine;
        public int getId_characteristic() {
            return id_characteristic;
        }
        public void setId_characteristic(int id_characteristic) {
            this.id_characteristic = id_characteristic;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public Maschine getMaschine() {
            return maschine;
        }
        public void setMaschine(Maschine maschine) {
            this.maschine = maschine;
        }
        public Characteristic() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }
```

And in your DAO package you have to create a interface that extends JPARepository for exemple :

```
public interface MaschineRepository extends JpaRepository<Maschine,Integer> {

}
```

then when you call MaschineRepository.findAll() you will get all the maschines with their Characteristics

Spring data dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

don't forget to add the database configuration in your application.properties if you work with spring boot

Comment: Your answer seems to be nice and correct but I have trouble to import the annotation for the Maschine pojo class. I have added org.springframework.data. Unoftunately eclipse suggests me to create my own annotation. can you post your imports either, please?

Comment: Yes of course :                                                                                       import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

Comment: I am sorry but I still have trouble.. My issue in Maschine class: The attribute strategy is undefined for the annotation type Generated. Eclipse advices me to add missing attributes and then adds value = { "" } which produces new issues

Comment: I think that your're problem is in the JPA dependency make sure that you add it in your pom.xml

Comment: I have added the following to my pom.xml:    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
    </dependency>

Comment: Try to build your project if you use maven  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896152/how-to-build-and-run-maven-projects-after-importing-into-eclipse-ide