# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I have seen many solutions in Stack Overflow but none of them worked for me.
So I am getting this exception. My pom.xml code is here

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
  <dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added jar file in tomcat/lib folder also. But nothing is working for me.

Comment: Did you do a maven update?

Comment: You should rebuild project with the new `pom.xml` for changes to take effect

Comment: By the way, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @GrayCygnus, you mean i need to delete current pom.xml and again create new pom.xml?

Comment: @PraveenRB i mean you should build the project again, check my answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rebuild your Maven project after adding new dependencies, either directly on Eclipse if you have the [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) built-in support (which you should, as explained and recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896152/how-to-build-and-run-maven-projects-after-importing-into-eclipse-ide) question),

By right-clicking on the project name and then doing `Maven->Update project` (as @BackSlash suggests)

Also, looking at your `pom.xml` you are not nesting that `<dependency>` inside the `<dependencies>` tag, my db connector (postgress) looks something like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.0.0.jre7</version>
    </dependency>

    ... more <dependency> here...
</dependencies>
```

You can check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/) great link that explains how to write `pom.xml` files when creating and building Java projects with Maven.

Edit:

Remember to call the driver exactly like "com.mysql.jdbc.**D**river", with capital 'd'.

Comment: Also, without rebuilding the project by hand, eclipse has an option for it. `Right-click on the project name->Maven->Update project` rebuilds the project and checks all dependencies (and downloads missing jars)

Comment: Edited the answer and added a great link for Maven in Java

Comment: sorry, i have done all changes but still not working

Comment: actually i had a nested dependencies tag, but i did not write it in question

Comment: can you add the java code that gives you the error, as well as the full stack trace? Also a better question title would be suitable

Comment: Please never ever recommend running `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. It's been officially retired for almost 2 years and has been breaking m2e eclipse integration for at least 4 years. It was designed to provide some integration between Eclipse and Maven before the advent of m2e and is not compatible with it.

Comment: @SteveC thats why I linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896152/how-to-build-and-run-maven-projects-after-importing-into-eclipse-ide) question where they indicate that. I will add it to the answer to clarify that also.

Comment: Your first sentence states to run it *if* you have m2e support. At best, that's the exact opposite of what you should do. If fact these days you should never use it because it's just way out of date.

Comment: @GrayCygnus, problem got solved i made a silly mistake.while loading drive class insted of writing Class.forname("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); i had written driver (d in small letter).

Comment: From now i will post qualified questions. Thanks for supporting me.

Comment: @PraveenRB no problem, glad I could help :) I will edit the answer to add this detail so it is useful for future users with similar problems.