# How to run a scala maven project on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide

I need to run [this maven Scala project](https://github.com/opencypher/caps-examples) with eclipse however when i click on run i didn't get any suggestion on how to run the project ?!

**update of question**

I get help from a contributor [here](https://github.com/opencypher/caps-examples/issues/2):

what was missing is :

- [Maven Integration for Scala ide](http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site/)
- Fixing the Seetings of the **Scala Compiler**

it works for him , but form me i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 9
```

any helps?

Comment: Did you import it as a maven project?

Comment: no the project have already it's dependencies set  so i just opened directly in eclipse

Comment: Don't - that only works in netbeans and intellij.  You must have m2e installed and then import an existing maven project.

Comment: ok i did that but i still didn't get no suggestion when i click on run.
what i get is : **The selection can not be launched, and there are no recent launches**

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896152/how-to-build-and-run-maven-projects-after-importing-into-eclipse-ide